# Evaluating $\int M(f)^p$ by parts for an $L_p$ function $f$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral

Let $f\in L_p(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $M$ denote the Hardy-Littlewood maximal operator, and $\lambda$ denote the distribution function of $M(f)$. The book I'm reading does this step:

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} M(f)^p=-\int_0^\infty\alpha^pd\lambda(\alpha)$$ which I understand. But then they apply integration by parts to get $$p\int_0^\infty\alpha^{p-1}\lambda(\alpha)d\alpha$$

This means that the other terms in the integration by parts vanished. That is, $$\alpha^p\lambda(\alpha)|_0^\infty=0$$ which I am struggling to show. I only managed to prove that $\alpha^p\lambda(\alpha)$ is bounded by the quantity $2^p/3^n||f||_p^p$. This would have helped me if I could show that $\alpha^p\lambda(\alpha)$ increases as $\alpha\rightarrow\infty\text{ or }0$.

Any suggestion would really help me.

Comment: I think the key is is notice that if $\phi$ is a monotone increasing (not zero) function then $$m\big(\phi(h(t))>\phi(\lambda)\big)\leq\frac{1}{\phi(\lambda)}\int_{\{\phi\circ h>\phi(\lambda)\}}\phi(h(t))\,m(dt)$$. Whence you get $$\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow\infty}\phi(\lambda)m\big(\phi(h(t))>\phi(\lambda)\big)\leq\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\{\phi\circ h>\phi(\lambda)\}}\phi(h(t))\,m(dt)=0$$

Comment: I changed your notation unintentionally as I was working the details for myself and my own idiosyncracies: ($m$ is a measure, $\lambda$ is an argument (your $\alpha$). Let me know if the idea in my comment is clear to you.